# Reflow text files in a two-colum layout

Tags: layout

Is it possible to reformat/reflow text files into two-column layouts (as in some newspapers)? I can do that in Word, but I'd rather do it in vim.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to accomplish... Do you want to split the screen into two columns and have different files (or different locations of the same file) in them? If so, you want windows and the `:vsplit` command. Or do you want to actually reformat/reflow your text into two columns? I'm afraid that concept would be very foreign to Vim, which is actually a text *editor* rather than a layout or typesetting tool... You could use Vim to write LaTeX or similar sources and have those tools typeset the contents for you... But have two columns in Vim, that would look odd... Can you explain?

Comment: Thanks filbranden, Yes I was hoping to reformat/reflow the text into two columns using Vim. You are quite right that unlike Word, Vim is not a typesetting tool. Calling both of them editors is confusing.

Comment: I think the OP wants two-column layout, like a newspaper. Probably vim can not do that, or maybe with some complex add-ons and scripting.

Comment: Try Dr. Chips MPage plugin: http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#MPAGE

Comment: Excellent link Christian, thanks.

Comment: So imagine VIM having lines 1-10 on the left side (80 columns) and on the right side having rows 11-20 (another 80 columns) and a 20 row text file is shown in only two rows on the terminal screen (using two columns) and it reads like a newspaper.  This would be a very useful feature on wide screens, as a user would be able to view twice as many rows, especially in scripts where the user is encouraged to keep each row of text at 80 columns in length or less.  I would definitely want this feature in vim, and possible in the linux shell in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this unix.se answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318345/301073), I would do

```
:%!pr -t -2 -w 200
```

Or some appropriate width (e.g., to insert twice `textwidth`, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>`=&textwidth*2`<kbd>Enter</kbd> after the `-w` ).

Comment: Good link Ben. I'd forgotten about fold and never heard of pr. With these two Linux commands I can get what I want. Of course I cannot edit the resulting columned output in Vim as it has no memory of Linux operations. But that is not a problem. I can edit in Vim but display using Linux commands. Thanks Ben, I will accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can reuse split windows for that.

Sequence of commands:

1. `:vsplit` to vertically split window
2. `:set scrollbind` to bind current window scroll with new window
3. `:<C-w>w` to go to new split window
4. `:<C-f>` to scroll this new window one page down
5. `:set scrollbind` to bind this window scroll to prev window

Now you have emulation of "two-column" layout.

I actually have this kind of command (named differently though, but here it would be called `TwoColumns`):

```
" Two columns.
" 1. Vertically split window
" 2. Offset it one screen
" 3. Scrollbind
command! TwoColumns
        \   exe "normal zR"
        \ | set noscrollbind
        \ | vsplit
        \ | set scrollbind
        \ | wincmd w
        \ | exe "normal \<c-f>"
        \ | set scrollbind
        \ | wincmd p
```

It additionally opens all folds, resets scrollbind and goes back to current window in the end.

PS, this command depends on default value of `splitright` (off by default). If `splitright` is set, one have to slightly change the command.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Maxim, this is very interesting, though it is not what I had in mind. I saw a similar idea in Vim Tips Wiki (https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/View_text_file_in_two_columns)

Comment: Might be nice also to remap `<c-f>` and `<c-b>` to scroll twice as far, so using them replaces all the visible content with new content.

Comment: @Rich then one should maintain set of autocommands and state to reset them back as soon as "two-column mode" is off. Which wouldn't be that trivial :)

Comment: This works very well!  make sure to use <ctr1-E> and <ctrl-Y> to adjust the viewport so that the appropriate line numbers are at the top and bottom of each view before setting the scrollbind

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that works is using paragraph formatting, visual block mode and virtualedit:

- `set textwidth=58`    <60 to allow spacing
- `set cc=60,120`       not required, but aids visualisation
- `set cul`             again not required, but aids visualisation
- `gqip` or  `gqq`      format all '}' paragraph(s) | or single line(s)
- `0ctrl-v<select>$`    select range of lines to paste on right side
- `d`                   deleted to reg 0 by default
- `set ve=all`          turn on virtual edit and relocate cursor on right at the start of where you want to insert
- `P`                   paste the text using shift-p will go under cursor location
- `set ve=`             undo virtualedit mode, some commands like `x` operate differently
- `set cc=`             undo colorcolumn
- `set nocul`           undo cursorline
- `set textwidth=`      unset or change textwidth, noting many times it's unset when coding

This results in

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccccccc
ddddddddddddddddd
```

becoming

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  ccccccccccccccccc
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb  ddddddddddddddddd
```

On the same note, splits as with Maxim Kim noted can be made to appear visually correct and if set up, you can
generally use your OS copy/paste function into a new buffer and then use visual mode to clean up. An addded benefit of
this is long fields are "automatically" wrapped. You may also want to look at

- `:left`
- `:center`
- `:right`
- `ctrl-v<select>I`

and using multiple buffers via splits or tabs for "parts" before pasting.