# How to edit file as vsplit panels?

Tags: vim-windows, split

As Vim user, it is useful to view more lines of source code.

Are there any tools which combine left and right panels when using `:vsplit` to split into two windows. Then move the cursor up/down.

[image]

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26876/9333

Comment: The alternative would be to write modular code where all context fits on one screen. Ah well, just a crazy idea by a deluded clean code cultist. (And yes, I also noticed it's a third party Makefile in the screenshot and you're not responsible for this mess.)